# How to add two services in Program.cs in ASP.NET Core 7 Web API?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I have two interfaces and I implemented both of them on two different classes. I want to register both services in my endpoint, but I get an error:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ModiranKhodro.Core.Contracts.Customers.Commands.ICustomerCommandRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ModiranKhodro.Data.Infra.Sql.Commands.Customers.CustomerCommandRepository': A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'ModiranKhodro.Core.Contracts.Customers.Commands.ICustomerCommandRepository'.
>
> ModiranKhodro.Core.Contracts.Customers.Commands.ICustomerCommandRepository(ModiranKhodro.Data.Infra.Sql.Commands.Customers.CustomerCommandRepository) -> ModiranKhodro.Core.Contracts.Customers.Commands.ICustomerCommandRepository)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`1[ModiranKhodro.Core.Contracts.Customers.Commands.Create.CreateCustomerCommand] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: ModiranKhodro.Core.ApplicationService.Customers.Commands.Create.CreateCustomerCommandHandler': A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'ModiranKhodro.Core.Contracts.Customers.Commands.ICustomerCommandRepository'.
> MediatR.IRequestHandler<ModiranKhodro.Core.Contracts.Customers.Commands.Create.CreateCustomerCommand>(ModiranKhodro.Core.ApplicationService.Customers.Commands.Create.CreateCustomerCommandHandler) -> ModiranKhodro.Core.Contracts.Customers.Commands.ICustomerCommandRepository(ModiranKhodro.Data.Infra.Sql.Commands.Customers.CustomerCommandRepository) -> ModiranKhodro.Core.Contracts.Customers.Commands.ICustomerCommandRepository)'

Here is my register code in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomerQueryRepository, CustomerQueryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomerCommandRepository, CustomerCommandRepository>();
```

I tried different ways but I didn't enough and also I want to register both services from every single ways.

Comment: Without seeing as much as a shred of code, this is **impossible** to answer ....

Comment: The error messages just tells us a circular dependency issue occoured ,you need  to share the codes of your CustomerCommandRepository, CreateCustomerCommandHandler

Comment: Actually I did this and my problem is solved.Thank you.

Comment: Hello, did you able to resolve your issue? Do you still have any concern on this? Let me know if you need further assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error description it telling us about the circular dependencies which means wihtin your code there are some component which has inter-dependency between them and they failed to compile because when A depended on B so we cannot build A because A needs B to build and here circular dependencies  comes in.

As [@marc-s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) already pointed out that we need more details in order to investigate your issue.

Apart from that, as you already figure that out, so just to enhance the point,for reference here.

You have shared, ICustomerQueryRepository and ICustomerCommandRepository inerface. While, encountering this kind of circular dependencies issue, make sure, your components have been designed accrodingly.

Therefore, please double check your interfaces and its implementation correctly. In order to overcome this error, we can simply get rid of the direct dependency between the component or module.

**Note:** You could take a [look at this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/circular-dependencies-between-modules) as reference.